# Swap key-value in PySpark RDD

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am working with PySpark RDD. When I generate (key-value) using map function, the position of these two are incorrect and need to be swapped.

Here is my map function:

```
rdd8=rdd5.map(lambda word : (word,1) )
rdd8.collect()
```

and I received this result:

```
 ('کاغذ', 1),
 ('داره', 1),
 ('و', 1),
 ('هر', 1),
 ('خطی', 1),
 ('را', 1),
 ('بکشید', 1),
 ('ثبت', 1),
 ('می', 1),
 ('کنه', 1),
 ('طراحی', 1),
 ('زیبا', 1),
 ('رنگ', 1),
 ('زرد', 1),
 ('زیبا', 1),
 ('صفر', 1),
 ('تاصد', 1),
 ('عالی', 1),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map rdd8 and swap the tuple elements:

```
new_rdd = rdd8.map(lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
```